# Numpy arrays in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to accomplish the following in a loop:

```
A1 = a/(a+b)
B1 = A1*Z1
A2 = B1*Z2
B2 = A2*Z1
A3 = B2*Z2
B3 = A3*Z1
.
.
```

I tried putting the values in a list like so:

```
val_A = []
val_B = []
val_A.append(A1)
val_B.append(B1)

for i in range(5):
    val_A.append(val_B[i]*Z1)
    val_B.append(val_A[i]*Z2)


Output
[0.9090909090909091, -0.4958677685950413, -0.4958677685950413, 0.270473328324568, 0.270473328324568]
```

It works for the first 2 numbers but then it repeats the number twice.  Can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: You forget to tell us how the output is supposed to look like. Also, your example is incomlete, we can't run the code.

Comment: It's not clear what your variables represent.  For  instance, what are `Z1` and `Z2` equal to?

Comment: Z1 and Z2 are just float variables.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
val_A = []
val_B = []
val_A.append(A1)
val_B.append(B1)

for i in range(5):
    val_A.append(val_B[-1] * Z2)
    val_B.append(val_A[-1] * Z1)
```

**Demo:**
(On a simple test case, to show that it works)

```
# Manual
Z1 = 2
Z2 = 3
A1 = 5
B1 = 7
A2 = B1*Z2
B2 = A2*Z1
A3 = B2*Z2
B3 = A3*Z1

print([A1, A2, A3], [B1, B2, B3])

# With for loop

val_A = []
val_B = []
val_A.append(A1)
val_B.append(B1)

for i in range(2):
    val_A.append(val_B[-1] * Z2)
    val_B.append(val_A[-1] * Z1)

print(val_A, val_B)
```

Yields:

```
[5, 21, 126] [7, 42, 252]
[5, 21, 126] [7, 42, 252]
```

**Explanation:**

The OP code mixes up Z1 and Z2 (the B's should be multiplied by Z2) and also  uses the wrong indices for choosing items from the lists (this code avoids that by using '-1' to always take the last item from each list).

Comment: What question is this the answer to? (I'm serious, I'd like to know what OP wants to do.)

Comment: Oh, that -1 did it.  Thanks.  I'm still learning.

Comment: The code is a loop that is equivalent to the pattern that the OP started (two lists A and B, with some initial values A1 and B1, where, for two constants Z2 and Z1, A[i > 1] = B[i - 1] * Z2 and B[i > 1] = B[i] * Z1). Beyond that, I have no idea what the purpose of the actual code is supposed to be, other than the immediate goal of easily generating more items in the lists...